# XmlSerializer, "Specified" suffix and IReflect

Tags: c#, reflection, xml-serialization

I've discovered that if a serializable *Field/Property* has a corresponding field of type *Boolean* having as a name the *Field/Property* name with "Specified" suffix, the XmlSerializer conditionally exclude that *Field/Property* from the serialization process. Nice!

So, I want to avoid the definition of those fields, and add them dynamically, at runtime...

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646258/how-can-i-add-dynamically-field-to-the-class-in-c), I found an interesting interface [IReflect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ireflect_members(v=VS.80).aspx), which I can use to "emulate" dynamic fields which are used by the XmlSerializer instances to exclude certain fields.

Would this work?

Comment: Can you comment on why you want to avoid those fields and do this at runtime? Do you want to serialize classes differently based upon some runtime calculated values, or you just want to avoid adding this additional properties?

Comment: this is amazing: framework authors actually hardcoded this into the depths of the xml serializer's reflection engine. what a design decision! where is this documented? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlReflectionImporter.cs,1214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take control of your xml serialization then you have two options. The first (which might not be appropriate here) it to use the attributes in the System.Xml.Serialization namespace to exclude properties. If you really need to do determine what gets serialized at runtime this might not be the best course of action.

See [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx)

The other way to do this is to implement the IXmlSerializable interface on your class and implement the ReadXml and WriteXml methods. This allows you to take control of exactly how your xml looks. See this question for additional info:

[custom xml serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109827/custom-xml-serialization)

However, as mentioned here [Mixing custom and basic serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641612/mixing-custom-and-basic-serialization) once you implement IXmlSerializable you are responsible for all the serialization logic for your type.

Comment: please don't post .NET 1.1 links unless explicitly requested.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Wow! Just realised that it was almost 1 year ago that I answered :-)

Answer (score 6):

I will extend answer of *Martin Peck*.
You can avoid serialization of the fields/properties with "Specified" suffix.
You should define that "*Specified" properties in your class and apply `[XmlIgnoreAttribute()]` to them.

Here is an example:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://yournamespace.com")]
public partial class YourObject
{
    private long sessionTimeoutInSecondsField;

    private bool sessionTimeoutInSecondsFieldSpecified;

    public long sessionTimeoutInSeconds
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sessionTimeoutInSecondsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sessionTimeoutInSecondsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool sessionTimeoutInSecondsSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sessionTimeoutInSecondsFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sessionTimeoutInSecondsFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You get use only getter for `*Specified` property and do not need to set `XmlIgnore`.

Answer (score 0):

Code sample as an extension to the provided answer;

WSDL:

```
<xs:simpleType name="vehicleType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="CAR" />
      <xs:enumeration value="BUS" />
      <xs:enumeration value="BIKE" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="advancedSearchRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="vehicleType" type="tns:vehicleType" />
      <xs:element name="search" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Generated .net SOAP client class

```
System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3056.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="your namespace")]
public partial class advancedSearchRequest : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private vehicleType vehicleTypeField;

    private bool vehicleTypeFieldSpecified;

    private string searchField;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public vehicleType vehicleType {
        get {
            return this.vehicleTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.vehicleTypeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("vehicleType");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool vehicleTypeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.vehicleTypeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.vehicleTypeFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("vehicleTypeSpecified");
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
    public string search {
        get {
            return this.searchField;
        }
        set {
            this.searchField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("search");
        }
    }

}
```

You can set "vehicleTypeFieldSpecified" = {true/false} to {serialize/omit} it;

```
advancedSearchRequest.vehicleTypeField = vehicleType.BIKE;
advancedSearchRequest.vehicleTypeFieldSpecified = true;
```

Resulting SOAP message;

```
<advancedSearchRequests>
 <vehicleType>BIKE</vehicleType>
 <search>abc</search>
</advancedSearchRequest>
```