# Pass value to SOAP API complex type

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, casting, wsdl

I'm calling a SOAP API using Server Reference, there is a complex type which requires weight values. I'm setting the values using the following code:

```
parcel objpcl = new parcel();
objpcl.weight = 10;
objpcl.length = 10;
objpcl.width = 10;
objpcl.depth = 10;
objpcl.girth = 10;
objpcl.combinedDimension = 10;
objpcl.volume = 10;
objpcl.value = 100;
```

The response returns and error stating "Invalid Weight". Here are the WSDL details:

```
  <xs:complexType name="parcel">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="weight" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="length" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="width" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="depth" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="girth" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="combinedDimension" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="volume" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="currency" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numberOfParts" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numberOfItems" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hangingGarment" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="theftRisk" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="multipleParts" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="catalogue" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="originOfParcel" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

When I make the call using SOAPUI the call completes without an error. Below is the complete code, I'm hard coding the values for now to complete my testing, so any recommendation will have to account for the fact that I will be populating from database values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HermesWebService;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RoutingWebServiceClient objHermesWebService = new RoutingWebServiceClient();
        objHermesWebService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "ababab";
        objHermesWebService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "abababa";

        deliveryRoutingRequest objRoutingRequest = new deliveryRoutingRequest();
        objRoutingRequest.clientId = "aba";
        objRoutingRequest.clientName = "aba";
        objRoutingRequest.userId = "abababa";
        objRoutingRequest.sourceOfRequest = "ababab";

        delRoutingRequestEntry objReqEntry = new delRoutingRequestEntry();
                objReqEntry.expectedDespatchDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-04-10T00:00:00");
    objReqEntry.countryOfOrigin = "US";

        customer objCust = new customer();
        objCust.customerReference1 = "12345";

        address objadr = new address();
        objadr.lastName = "Robinson";
        objadr.streetName = "Eastern Perimeter Road";
        objadr.addressLine1 = "London Heathrow Airport";
        objadr.city = "London";
        objadr.region = "Hounslow";
        objadr.postCode = "TW6 2GE";
        objadr.countryCode = "GB";

        parcel objpcl = new parcel();
        objpcl.weight = 10m;
        objpcl.length = 10m;
        objpcl.width = 10m;
        objpcl.depth = 10m;
        objpcl.girth = 10m;
        objpcl.combinedDimension = 10m;
        objpcl.volume = 10m;
        objpcl.value = 100;

        objCust.address = objadr;
        objReqEntry.customer = objCust;
        objReqEntry.parcel = objpcl;

        objRoutingRequest.deliveryRoutingRequestEntries = new [] {objReqEntry};


        //var request = new delroutingrequestentry
        //{
        //    addressvalidationrequired = false
        //};

        //request.parcel = objpcl;
        //objroutingrequest.deliveryroutingrequestentries[0] = request;

        var x = objHermesWebService.validateDeliveryAddress(objRoutingRequest);

    }
}
```

After running the Microsoft Service Trace Viewer it appears that the Parcel element is not making it to the API call, here is a copy of part of the trace viewer log:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="58ef72b0-fd4d-475f-9347-5f1ba25f5987" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">7f7337fb-8db5-4b84-8e6c-44d7f43d561a</ActivityId>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<validateDeliveryAddress xmlns="http://v2.web.domain.routing.hermes.co.uk/">
<deliveryRoutingRequest>
<clientId xmlns="">aba</clientId>
<clientName xmlns="">aba</clientName>
<userId xmlns="">ababab</userId>
<sourceOfRequest xmlns="">ababab</sourceOfRequest>
<deliveryRoutingRequestEntries xmlns="">
<deliveryRoutingRequestEntry>
<customer>
<address>
<lastName>Robinson</lastName>
<streetName>Eastern Perimeter Road</streetName>
<addressLine1>London Heathrow Airport</addressLine1>
<city>London</city>
<region>Hounslow</region>
<postCode>TW6 2GE</postCode>
<countryCode>GB</countryCode>
</address>
<customerReference1>12345</customerReference1>
</customer>
<parcel></parcel>
<expectedDespatchDate>2015-04-10</expectedDespatchDate>
<countryOfOrigin>US</countryOfOrigin>
</deliveryRoutingRequestEntry>
</deliveryRoutingRequestEntries>
</deliveryRoutingRequest>
</validateDeliveryAddress>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: and what response are you expecting to receive

Comment: @Coder1409 an XML response stating if the address was or was not found. At this point I receive and error XML response stating "Invalid Weight"

Comment: try to send a valid weight like a non null weight may be the service doesn't accept non null values

Comment: Yes I've tried both, set all values to 10 received same XML error. The SOAPUI call works with 0 or 10 or any other numeric value.

Comment: Additional Information: I used Microsoft Service Trace Viewer and it appears that the Parcel element is not being populated during the API call: 
<customer>
<address>
<lastName>Robinson</lastName>
<streetName>Eastern Perimeter Road</streetName>
<addressLine1>London Heathrow Airport</addressLine1>
<city>London</city>
<region>Hounslow</region>
<postCode>TW6 2GE</postCode>
<countryCode>GB</countryCode>
</address>
<customerReference1>12345</customerReference1>
</customer>
<parcel></parcel>
<expectedDespatchDate>2015-04-10</expectedDespatchDate>
<countryOfOrigin>US</countryOfOrigin>

Comment: Additional Information: when I step through the code the Parcel element is present within the objRoutingRequest object. (var x = objHermesWebService.validateDeliveryAddress(objRoutingRequest);) But when the validateDeliveryAddress service is called the Parcel element is empty.

Comment: Additional Information: Strings do appear in the Parcel Element, so the problem seems to be specific to numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a feeling the problem had a simple solution that I was overlooking. Each decimal field has a corresponding field which ends in Specified. The Specified field is a boolean which must be set to true in order for the field value to be sent during the serialization. There are additional post ([XmlSerializer, "Specified" suffix and IReflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261038/xmlserializer-specified-suffix-and-ireflect)) which define better ways of accomplishing this; for now I manually specify:

```
    var objpcl = new parcel
    {
        weight = 10, weightSpecified = true,
        length = 10, lengthSpecified = true,
        width = 10, widthSpecified = true,
        depth = 10, depthSpecified = true, 
        girth = 10, girthSpecified = true,
        combinedDimension = 10, combinedDimensionSpecified = true,
        volume = 10, volumeSpecified = true,
        value = 100, valueSpecified = true,
        numberOfParts = 1, numberOfPartsSpecified = true,
        numberOfItems = 10, numberOfItemsSpecified = true,            
        description = "Test Package",
        originOfParcel = "US",
    };
```

If I spent a little more time reviewing the WSDL file I would have noticed the following:

```
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public decimal weight { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool weightSpecified { get; set; }

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool weightSpecified
{
    get
    {
        return this.weightFieldSpecified;
    }
    set
    {
        this.weightFieldSpecified = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("weightSpecified");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.